# Command Encoded in Powershell FAIL

Tags: powershell

I discovered that the command uncoded bad, but I do not understand what is wrong:

My Code :

```
$command = "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://localhost/update_program.exe','updater.exe'); Start-Process 'updater.exe'"
$bytes = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
echo $encodedCommand
```

Return

```
KABOAGUAdwAtAE8AYgBqAGUAYwB0ACAAUwB5AHMAdABlAG0ALgBOAGUAdAAuAFcAZQBiAEMAbABpAGU
AbgB0ACkALgBEAG8AdwBuAGwAbwBhAGQARgBpAGwAZQAoACcAaAB0AHQAcAA6AC8ALwBsAG8AYwBhAG
wAaABvAHMAdAAvAHUAcABkAGEAdABlAF8AcAByAG8AZwByAGEAbQAuAGUAeABlACcALAAnAHUAcABkA
GEAdABlAHIALgBlAHgAZQAnACkAOwAgAFMAdABhAHIAdAAtAFAAcgBvAGMAZQBzAHMAIAAnAHUAcABk
AGEAdABlAHIALgBlAHgAZQAnAA==
```

I try :

```
powershell -encodedCommand KABOAGUAdwAtAE8AYgBqAGUAYwB0ACAAUwB5AHMAdABlAG0ALgBOAGUAdAAuAFcAZQBiAEMAbABpAGUAbgB0ACkALgBEAG8AdwBuAGwAbwBhAGQARgBpAGwAZQAoACcAaAB0AHQAcAA6AC8ALwBsAG8AYwBhAGwAaABvAHMAdAAvAHUAcABkAGEAdABlAF8AcAByAG8AZwByAGEAbQAuAGUAeABlACcALAAnAHUAcABkAGEAdABlAHIALgBlAHgAZQAnACkAOwAgAFMAdABhAHIAdAAtAFAAcgBvAGMAZQBzAHMAIAAnAHUAcABkAGEAdABlAHIALgBlAHgAZQAnAA==
```

Return :

<sup>**Editor's note:** The symptom below is inconsistent with the code above, which is correct. There may not be a problem left to solve.</sup>

```
Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
In line: 1 Character: 2
+ - < <<< encodeCommand KABOAGUAdwAtAE8AYgBqAGUAYwB0ACAAUwB5AHMAdABlAG0ALgBOAGUA
dAAuAFcAZQBiAEMAbABpAGUAbgB0ACkALgBEAG8AdwBuAGwAbwBhAGQARgBpAGwAZQAoACcAaAB0AHQ
AcAA6AC8ALwBsAG8AYwBhAGwAaABvAHMAdAAvAHUAcABkAGEAdABlAF8AcAByAG8AZwByAGEAbQAuAG
UAeABlACcALAAnAHUAcABkAGEAdABlAHIALgBlAHgAZQAnACkAOwAgAFMAdABhAHIAdAAtAFAAcgBvA
GMAZQBzAHMAIAAnAHUAcABkAGEAdABlAHIALgBlAHgAZQAnAA==
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (-:String) [], ParentContainsErrorR
   ecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

Because my command coded fails?

Comment: What's the problem running as a command? `powershell.exe -command "<#your command goes here#>"`

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve, i.e. what do you need the base64-encoded command for?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, new answer as the question has changed quite drastically.

Try

```
#Encode Command
$command = "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://localhost/update_program.exe','updater.exe'); Start-Process 'updater.exe'"
$bytes = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
echo $encodedCommand

#Execute command
powershell.exe -EncodedCommand $encodedcommand
```

This should work so long as the statements in `$command` are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question at first. I think you were trying to ask how to stop Powershell from executing the string you assign to $command. If so then try the following code

```
powershell -command {
    $command = [string] $null; $command += '(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(';
    $command += "'http://localhost/update_program.exe','updater.exe') ; 
    Start-Process 'updater.exe'"; $bytes = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command); 
    $encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes); echo $encodedCommand
}
```

Microsoft wanted smart processing of variables to enable greater compatibility between variables and functions. I think it got confused when parsing your command. What I tried was to break up the string assignation so that Powershell didn't assume that the string was a set of instructions. The single statement above calls Powershell, assigns a null string to $command, twice concatenates with strings which Powershell cannot confuse and then outputs $encodedCommand at the end. Is this what you were after?

Comment: Hello , I'm trying to do is run all code the initial post in one command.Becouse I can not do a CreateProcess ( ) to do , so I thought that if I do everything in a command could read the response powershell with the encoded command

Comment: Sorry, @MattOlsen, I may have misunderstood. Do you want to 

[a.)Encode the String $command into a Base64String and output to the user]

[b.) Execute the three statements in the String $command in Powershell] 

or

[c.) Something else.]

Comment: Your command returns me :

Missing closing brace '}' in block instruction .

Comment: It's there, I just stick the brace on it's own line :)